# How to use python requests to PUT a pmml model to openscoring

Tags: python-requests, pmml

I'm trying to use python requests to PUT a .pmml model to a local openscoring server.
This works (from directory containing DecisionTreeIris.pmml):

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @DecisionTreeIris.pmml -H "Content-type: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/openscoring/model/DecisionTreeIris
```

This doesn't:

```
import requests
file = '/Users/weitzenfeld/IntelliJProjects/openscoring/openscoring-server/etc/DecisionTreeIris.pmml'
r = requests.put('http://localhost:8080/openscoring/model/DecisionTreeIris', files={'file': open(file, 'rb')})
r.text
```

returns:

```
u'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 415 </title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 415</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /openscoring/model/DecisionTreeIris. Reason:\n<pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre></p>\n<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

I also tried:

```
r = requests.put('http://localhost:8080/openscoring/model/DecisionTreeIris', files={'file': open(file, 'rb')}, headers={'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'text/xml'})
r.text
```

which returns:

```
u'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 406 </title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 406</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /openscoring/model/DecisionTreeIris. Reason:\n<pre>    Not Acceptable</pre></p>\n<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Note that my python attempt is the same as in the accepted answer to this question: [Using Python to PUT PMML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320021/using-python-to-put-pmml).

Also, someone with >1500 rep should consider making an 'openscoring' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to put data, not the file handler:

```
r = requests.put('http://localhost:8080/openscoring/model/DecisionTreeIris', data=open(file, 'rb'), headers={'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'text/xml'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the annotations of the method `org.openscoring.service.ModelResource#deploy(String, HttpServletRequest)` for valid request/response MIME types.

The first request fails because the server only accepts `application/xml` and `text/xml` payloads. The second request fails, because the server emits `application/json` payloads, but your client is only willing to accept `text/xml` payloads.

Comment: I've checked the annotations, and read the requests docs, but I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: In your second attempt, change the headers to the following: `headers={'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'application/json'}`.

Comment: Error 400: Bad Request